# Calculate the determinant of a matrix multiplied by itself confirmation

Tags: linear-algebra, determinant

If $ \det B = 4$ is then is $ \det(B^{10}) = 4^{10}$?

Does that also mean that $\det(B^{-2}) = \frac{1}{\det(B)^2} $

Or do I have this completely wrong?

Answer (score 6):

This is all correct and follows from the homomorphism property $\det(AB)=\det(A)\det(B)$, $\det(I)=1$ of the determinant.

Answer (score 1):

$det(B^2)$ means $ det(B*B)$ means at first, By multiplying two matrices you are getting a matrix and then you are finding determinant of that matrix

Similarly, $det(B^{10})$ means at first you are multiplying 10 matrices , that will give you a matrix and then finding the determinant

But in the case of the negative power only $B^{-m} $where m is a positive number
it is defined with respect to $B^{-1}$ that is $(B^{-1})^m$
hence, if $B^{-1}$ is defined then we can define $B^{-m}$
Here $det(B)\neq  0 $  therefor B is not singular hence $B^{-1}$ exists
So it has the menaing

Comment: Nope. If $B$ is invertible and if $k \in \mathbb{Z}$ is negative, then it is absolutely standard practice to define $B^{k} :=(B^{-1})^{|k|}$.

Comment: Thanks @BranimirĆaćić for pointing me out